# Characterization of $\lambda,\mu\vdash n$ for which ${n\choose\mu}\mid{n\choose\lambda}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

In view of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336208/how-to-prove-that-frac5m5nmn3mn3nm-is-a-natural-numbe), I was wondering about general characterizations of $\mu,\lambda\vdash n$ for which

$${n\choose\mu}\,\left|\,{n\choose\lambda}\right.,$$

(see [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) and [integer partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)) or equivalently

$$\frac{\mu_1!\mu_2!\cdots\mu_s!}{\lambda_1!\lambda_2!\cdots\lambda_r!}\in{\bf Z}.$$

For instance, just through pen-and-paper brute forcing, it seems ${n\choose a}\mid{n\choose b}$ implies $a\equiv\pm1$ mod $n$, and in those cases the corresponding $b$ are somewhat sprinkled about, for $n\le10$ and $a,b\in\bf N$.

I'm interested in any research or thoughts on sufficient conditions, or necessary conditions, or known families of cases, or conclusions for small $s,r$, or combinatorial interpretations of the resulting ratios when said ratios do happen to be integral, or compilations of pairs of partitions satisfying the condition for feasibly small $n$.

Comment: What does $\mu,\lambda \vdash n$ mean? Maybe it should be $\mu, \lambda \le n$...

Comment: @coffeemath: Please see the intro part of the Wikipedia entry for integer partitions that I gave a link for right after using the notation in my question: *"The notation λ⊢n means that λ is a partition of n."*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the partition of $n$ notation. Nice question. +1