# Prove divisibilty through inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $m,n$ be positive integers. Prove that
> $$m!n!(3m+n)!(3n+m)!|(5m)!(5n)!$$

My idea is to prove the following inequality $$\lfloor 5x\rfloor+\lfloor 5y\rfloor\ge \lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor y\rfloor +\lfloor 3x+y\rfloor+\lfloor x+3y\rfloor,0\le x,y<1$$I was stuck at this part. Could anyone have a nice approach to this inequality?

Comment: Check this inequality. Hint $[x]+[y] \leq [x+y]$

Comment: @AdamWrzesiński I believe that is not sufficient for this problem.

Comment: This is USAMO 1975/1. For solutions, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336208/how-to-prove-that-frac5m5nmn3mn3nm-is-a-natural-numbe?noredirect=1)